# Enable logging in Apache CXF generated client

Tags: apache, logging, cxf

I followed directions on CXF web site to enable logging of SOAP requests, but cannot see any logging going on in my logs. 
I have log4j, so I added `-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger` to Tomcat jvm args, then I created `cxf.xml` and put into classpath. I also added logger  into log4j config.
Nothing gets logged.
What can be a problem?

```
cxf.xml:
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the `LoggingInInterceptor/LoggingOutInterceptor` and am not sure about your bus configuration but you should be sure to also added a correct logger (with the correct name) to your log4j configuration.

In the Apache CXF - [2.5 Migration Guido](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/25-migration-guide.html) you will find the usefull information

> The Logging interceptors now log using service specific
>   categories/loggers instead of just
>   LoggingInInterceptor/LoggingOutInterceptor. The names of the logger
>   that is used is
>   org.apache.cxf.services.ServiceName.PortName.PortTypeName. This allows
>   the user to configure specific per service filters and formatters in
>   their logging configuration.

I have written a [blog post](http://frvabe.blogspot.de/2014/02/logging-requestresponse-messages-with.html) about logging with Apache CXF that provides all information I needed to enable request/response logging in my application.